# python regex tokenization custom characters to be splitting points

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

I want to tokenize a sentence (purely with regex without having to install NLTK or similar). I want the tokenizer to:

- split around hyphens '-' and apostrophes "'" --> e.g. ( I haven't heard good-news:: I haven ' t heard good - news )
- split around all other characters if only followed by a space --> e.g. ( I have, some 16,000.13 dollars (A) to spare :: I have , some 16,000.13 dollars ( A ) to spare)

I created this function, but it still does not split around "(":

```
def tok(txt): #we want to make sure that only apostrophs and hyphens are splitting points, and all other non alpha characters not followed by space to be non-spliting points
    sub=re.sub(r'(?u)(\W)(?!\S)',r' \1 ',txt)
    sub=re.sub(r"(?u)([\-\'\[\(\{])",r' \1 ',sub) #will need to add more exceptions
    return [v for v in re.split('(?u)\s+',sub) if v]
```

Comment: Show expected outputs as well. First two rules doesn't describe about `(`

Comment: I did, in the examples to each point

Comment: Could you put the desired output in a python list so that it's clearer?

Comment: So you want to split based apostrophes **or** hyphens only?

Comment: It does not split around "(" since it isn't followed by a white space but in your example followed by an "A". You have to create an extra rule for that.

Comment: Nope: apostrophes or hyphens unconditionally, BUT any other non-alpha character ONLY IF they are NOT followed by space

Comment: hmmmm, seems I got confused with the logic of it

Comment: That would split up the 16,000.13.

Comment: @zx81 Yes, learned it the hard way once.

Answer (score 1):

**A Python Oddity: re.split doesn't split on zero-width matches**

Most regex engines allow you to split on a zero-width match, i.e., a certain position in the string. For instance, you can use the lookbehind `(?<=&)` to split if the previous character is a `&`. However, Python does not allow you to split on zero-width matches—unless you use the `regex` module with the `V1` flag turned on. To see this, try:

```
re.split("(?=&)", "a&fine&tree")
```

and

```
regex.split("(?V1)(?=&)", "a&fine&tree")
```

**Splitting vs. Match All**

So if we want to stick to `re`, splitting may be awkward. Luckily, splitting a string and matching all the tokens of interest are two sides of the same coin. In this case, matching is faster and gives you the same array.

Please note that I have adjusted your rules based on your desired output, but we can tweak them back. For instance, it does sound like you want to want to split unconditionally around `(` since there is no space after `(` in `(A`. Also digits sound like they should be treated like letters.

Just use this:

```
result = re.findall("[-'()]|[^a-z0-9 ](?= )|(?:[a-z0-9]|[^-'()a-z0-9 ](?! ))+", subject, re.IGNORECASE)
```

**The tokens:**

```
I
haven
'
t
heard
good
-
news
I
have
,
some
16,000.13
dollars
(
A
)
to
spare
```

**References**

- [The Elements of Good Regex Style](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html) (search for "split")
- [re does not split on zero-width matches](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-python.html#resplitzero)